# How can i parse MT202 Swift message into python Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I convert MT202  Swift message into python pandas data frame? Below is the message am trying to parse

```
{1:F01ABC1234567890000000000}{2:I202XYZ12345678XN}{3:{108:PU8AZEGXLFAK53LA}{111:001}{121:ea004539-82d9-4fb3-93dc-23121ff34f91}}{4:
:20:PQRST12345678912
:21:PQRST12345678912
:32A:200609USD7833,25
:57A:BBBBBB44
:58A:AAAAAAAA
:50K:/CH720023023054423061B
TEST TEST DATA
TEST  TEST DATA 25
WORLD UK LONDON
:52A:ABC12345678
:57A:AAAAAAAA
:59:/123456789
TEST TEST
:70:REG.TEST TEST TEST
:33B:USD7833,25
-}
```

Comment: What should the resulting dataframe look like for that message?

Comment: Are you sure that's a valid MT202? The first line looks as though it might be incomplete. Do you need a dataframe? I ask that because it rather depends on what you want to do with the data. That might determine the best Python internal format

Comment: Message is complete i have just anonymized the BICs , i want the swift tags to be columns in dataframe so seperate columns for :20: , :21: and so on , if possible columns for 1: , and 2: as well